# Using Is Operator with Value Types C#

Tags: c#, casting, typechecking

What am I missing? I do not see an answer on stackoverflow, but could have missed it. It seems like the "is" operator should work (i.e. evaluate to true) for the case where

```
short j = 1;
int k = 2; 

if (j is int)
   Console.WriteLine("all values of j will fit into k");
else
   Console.WriteLine("all values of j will not fit into k");
```

I tried making the int and short nullable which did not work as well. The rationale for the conditional being true is that all values of short will fit into a variable of type int (which is potentially wrong based on the result - i.e. the "If (j is in)" evaluates to false. Thanks

Comment: short is not type of int

Comment: short is `Int16` different from `int` (`Int32`)

Comment: And int is `Int32` for completeness. Similarly long is `Int64` and byte is `UInt8`. Also there are unsigned versions that start with u/U (except sbyte which is `Int8`).

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation of the operator.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments, especially for how a short is not an int and how Int16 is not an Int32. Before these comments/answers, I would have expected, as well, that "if (j is Int32)" to evaluate to true when "Int16 j=5;". You are right Eric, more documentation is usually better. This just did not make sense based on documentation I had read looking at "is" and "implicit" casting followed by some testing. Thanks again for the clarifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`is` means "Is derived from", roughly.

Thus the following will return true.

```
j is short
j is object
k is int
k is object
```

The following will return false.

```
j is int
k is short
```

Since `int` and `short` do not inherit from one another in anyway.

To answer the question of "does an X fit in a Y", I do not believe there is a built in mechanism for that, since typically you need to bake the answer into your logic anyway.

If you just want to know the answer, typically C# is very good at providing implicit conversions that match your definition of `is` while only providing explicit conversions otherwise.

For example you can implicitly convert an `int` to a `double` not because they are the same thing, but because every `int` has a perfect `double` representation.

Comment: Great answer - thanks! I especially liked your comments regarding implicit conversion. Best

Answer (score 8):

> The rationale for the conditional being true is that all values of `short` will fit into a variable of type `int`.

You're holding a paperback copy of the book `The Hobbit`, and someone asks you "is that thing you're holding a movie?"  Do you say yes, because there's was a movie made of the book? Or do you say "no, I'm holding a paperback book, and a book is not a movie." ?

Just because there is an int that corresponds to every short does not make a short an int.  The `is` operator tells you **whether the thing you have in hand *is* of a particular type**, hence the name "the `is` operator". It doesn't tell you **whether there is a different thing of a different type that happens to correspond to the thing you have in hand**.

Answer (score 2):

`short` is `System.Int16`. `int` is `System.Int32`. These are two completely different structs.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a short function that did this type of conversion.  Perhaps you can extrapolate from it what you need.

```
private boolean IsInteger(object expression)
{
    var numericTypes = new HashSet<Type>(
                                        {
                                             typeof(Byte),
                                             typeof(SByte),
                                             typeof(Int16),
                                             typeof(UInt16),
                                             typeof(Int32),
                                             typeof(UInt32)
                                        });
    return expression != null && numericTypes.Contains(expression.GetType());
}
```